# R Removing odd middledot in scraped HTML

Tags: r, web-scraping, rstudio

I'm still on my generic news web scraper project and have come across an odd one I can't fathom (again).  Using RStudio I am stripping HTML to leave plain ASCII and saving this out to a CSV file.  But in that file there are what appear to be random spurious characters.

For example: "`at large.Â  And what`" (the Â being the spurious character).

Loading the CSV into RStudio it displays differently with those characters showing as what appears to be a red bounded middle-dot.

## [image: Funny RStudio red middle-dot]

Can anyone shed any light on what this might be, or even better how to find this in the HTML and gsub it out?

Comment: Try `txt <- gsub("[^\x20-\x7F]", "", txt)`. If it works, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Beauty thanks worked a treat.. What are those those Regex matches - haven't seen those before?